# How to update geometry in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, geometry, editing

I'm just starting with ArcObjects and I want to update coordinates of geometry vertices. Specifically, I want to swap X, Y coordinates for each vertex of polygons (which can be multipart and have inner rings).

I've found web help topic [Updating geometry of existing features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000003m3000000) where `ITransform2D` interface is suggested. But it's methods does not seem solve my problem directly. I think I can use `Move` method, but it requires calculating dx and dy.

Is it possible to do coordinate replacement in ArcObjects like in Python `vertex.X = vertex.Y` but without recreating geometry? (this is quite tricky in Python for polygons with inner rings)

I adapted @vinayan code, but it does nothing. What do I miss?

```cs
protected override void OnClick()
{
    IMxDocument mxDocument = ((IMxDocument)(ArcMap.Application.Document)); // Explicit Cast   
    IContentsView currentContentsView = mxDocument.CurrentContentsView;
    IFeatureLayer featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)currentContentsView.SelectedItem; // Explicit Cast
    IFeatureClass featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

    //Get the Feature or FeatureCursor as you like..
    IFeatureClass pFC = featureClass;
    IFeature polygonFeature = pFC.GetFeature(1);

    IPointCollection pPtsColl = (IPointCollection)polygonFeature.ShapeCopy;

    //swap X and Y
    double tempValue;
    IPoint pPoint;

    for (int i = 0; i < pPtsColl.PointCount; i++)
    {
        pPoint = pPtsColl.get_Point(i);
        tempValue = pPoint.X;
        pPoint.X = pPoint.Y;
        pPoint.Y = tempValue;
    }

    //Update Feature
    polygonFeature.Shape = (IGeometry)pPtsColl;
    polygonFeature.Store();
}
```

Comment: I assume you have tried to debug. Does it reach the for loop? Does it move the expected number of times though the loop?

Comment: I was not using an updated pointcollection earlier to update the geometry..fixed now..

Comment: Swapping the coordinates is an [affine transformation](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/ComponentHelp/esriGeometry/AffineTransformation2D.htm).  Use a=c=e=f=0 and b=d=1.

Comment: @whuber - so simple!! never even thought of it..

Comment: @vinayan, @whuber - but which `IAffineTransformation2D` method should I use? I haven't found one with such set of parameters.

Comment: I do not think any such parameters exist in ArcObjects..My guess is you can use IAffineTransformation2D3GEN.DefineFromControlPoints(ref fromPoints, ref toPoints) where, fromPoints = array of IPoint from pointCollection and toPoints = array of IPoint where X and Y are reversed..@whuber hope i am guessing right...

Comment: @vinayan Did you follow the link to the AffineTransformation2D coclass in my comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below Snippet could help..

```cs
//Get the Feature or FeatureCursor as you like..
IMxDocument pMxdoc = (IMxDocument)m_application.Document;
IMap pMap = pMxdoc.FocusMap;

IFeatureLayer pFtrLyr = (IFeatureLayer)pMap.get_Layer(0);
IFeatureClass pFC = pFtrLyr.FeatureClass;

IFeature polygonFeature = pFC.GetFeature(yourobjectid);

IPointCollection pPtsColl = (IPointCollection)polygonFeature.ShapeCopy;

double tempValue;
IPoint pPoint;

IPointCollection updColl = new PolygonClass();

for (int i = 0; i < pPtsColl.PointCount; i++)
{
    pPoint = pPtsColl.get_Point(i);
    tempValue = pPoint.X;
    pPoint.X = pPoint.Y;
    pPoint.Y = tempValue;

    object missing = Type.Missing;

    updColl.AddPoint(pPoint, ref missing, ref missing);
}

polygonFeature.Shape = (IGeometry)updColl;
polygonFeature.Store();
```

The best solution would be to follow @WHuber's Comment to do an affine transformation..something which can be done using `IAffineTransformation2D`..So there will be no need to worry about Multipart polygons and polygons with hole..

Comment: Thanks for this code. Unfortunately I'm stuck in `foreach` loop. I get error: _foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPointCollection'_. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Marcin -fixed now..didn't check using IDE ;-)

Comment: I've posted adapted code as Edit - it compiles but does nothing.

Comment: @Marcin - should work now...just modified

Comment: Thanks again. Now it works for simple polygons (multipart and with void polygons are not recreated correctly) and is good starting point for futher development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look at IPointCollection and the IPoint interface.